# wordpress shopping cart e commerce chase paymentech

Tags: e-commerce, wordpress, shopping-cart

Does any one here know of any plugin or have in any way integrated "CHASE PAYMENTECH GATEWAY" for CHECKOUT ?

I have searched for wp plugin that supports chase paymentech but to no avail?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a Chase Paymentech Gateway plugin that plugins into the Shopp shopping cart plugin for Wordpress. If you are interested in purchasing the plugin just shoot me an email for more information: nick at getrouty.com